# How to pass date variable in SFTP data path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a path with a variable value which contains yesterday date. I need to get files using SFTP. Here is my try.

```
#/bin/bash

TS=$(date -d '30 mins ago' +"%Y%m%d")

sshpass -p '12#$' sftp -P 2222 User_New@10.18.16.14 <<'END_SFTP'
get /newNE/PSData$TS*  /data/processedfiles
END_SFTP
```

But `TS` date value is not passing to remote server to get data.

```
File "/newNE/PSData$TS*" not found.
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parameter expansion (and command substitution and arithmetic expansion and line continuation handling) to be performed inside a here document, no part of the delimiter must be quoted, so:

```
#! /bin/sh -

ts=$(date -d '30 mins ago' +"%Y%m%d")

SSHPASS='12#$' sshpass -e sftp -P 2222 User_New@10.18.16.14 <<END_SFTP
get /newNE/PSData$ts* /data/processedfiles
END_SFTP
```

Also note:

- passwords should not be passed on the command line which is publicly available in the output of `ps` or sometimes in some accounting logs. Passing  them as environment  variables is generally fine as that's generally considered private. Even better would be to use public key authentication. You'll want to make sure read access to the script is restricted as well as it contains that password.
- shebangs start with `#!` followed by the path to the interpreter. [Adding a `-` is also good practice](/q/351729).  With just `#/bin/bash`, that would be only a comment, so in the absence of a shebang, your system would likely run `sh` to interpret the script.
- Here however, there's nothing `bash`-specific in that script, so you might as well use `sh` and remove that dependency to `bash` (and likely use fewer resources when running the script unless you're on a system where `/bin/sh` is `bash`).
- Here, you do have a dependency on GNU `date` (for that non-standard `-d` option) which is even less portable than `bash` (bash is the GNU shell but is also commonly found on non-GNU systems). If using `bash`, you could remove that dependency by defining `ts` as `printf -v ts '%(%Y%m%d)T' "$(( EPOCHSECONDS - 30 * 60 ))"` (after `printf -v EPOCHSECONDS '%(%s)T' -1` with older versions of `bash`).